# JsonConvert deserializes list of random objects into list of requested objects created with default constructor

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 with the package Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3.

I'm trying to de-serialize an incoming JSON string into a `List<Person>`. When the JSON string is an array of random objects, the result is actually a `List<Person>` of the same length as the incoming array and each `Person` seems to have been created with the default constructor!

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

De-serialization example:

```cs
string json = "[{\"random\": \"stuff\"}, {\"whatever\": 24}]";
var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

`persons` is a list with 2 `Person` objects that have both `Name` `null` and `Age` `null`. This seems like really strange default behavior!

I want to throw an error if the incoming array has even a single object that isn't a proper `Person`. I wan them explicitly to have a `Name` and an `Age`, even if they're null. Example: I want `"[{"Name": "Bob", "Age":null}]"` to become a `Person` with `Name`=`"Bob"` and `Age` equals `null`. I only care that they explicitly define all the properties.

How can this be done without changing the `Person` class?

**UPDATE:** For future reference, the linked questions cover my needs because I want to do *both* of these things at the same time.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm . (Found by googling "json.net throw if unexpected property", 3rd link)

Comment: @canton7 `MissingMemberHandling.Error` is only a partial solution. If I provide `[{"Name":"Bob"}]` that's going to create a `Person`. I want it to throw because `Age` is missing on the original JSON string.

Comment: You are missing an object above person.
IMO it tries to convert `{\"random\": \"stuff\"}` and `{\"whatever\": 24}` as both different persons.
Could you try something like:
`[{
{\"random\": \"stuff\"}, {\"whatever\": 24}
}]` ?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @igg you tell deserializer that you have 2 different persons, but you want it to treat it as a one person. you can do it by putting your string into one object, so just add { 'yourjsonstringgoeshere'}

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik No, I don't want to treat it as 1 person, it should try to convert each object into a `Person`. I want it to throw errors, because the objects aren't `Person`

Comment: @igg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264547/what-exceptions-does-newtonsoft-json-deserializeobject-throw

Comment: @igg Use that in conjunction with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655502/json-net-require-all-properties-on-deserialization ?

Comment: If your **model** has properties that your **JSON** may lack, and you want that to be an error, see [Json.NET require all properties on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29655502/3744182).  Conversely if your **JSON** may have properties that your **model** lacks, and you want that to be an error, see [Detect if deserialized object is missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21030712/3744182).  Since you seem to want both, this looks to be a duplicate of both, agree?

Comment: And if you want to log the errors and continue see [Ignore parsing errors during JSON.NET data parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26108527/3744182) and [What exceptions does Newtonsoft.Json.DeserializeObject throw?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26264547/3744182).

Comment: @dbc You are right, I want both. The answers you link cover my needs. Is there a way to mark a question as a duplicate of 2 other questions?

Comment: Yes, I'll do it